# What is wrong with this layout? Unable to call block from non-local.xml file

Tags: layout

Inside my local.xml file I have this

```
<default>
    <label>All Pages</label>
    <block type="page/html" name="root" output="toHtml">
        ...
        <block type="core/template" name="sidebarblock" as="sidebarblock" template="abcpage/html/sidebarblock.phtml">
            <block type="core/template" name="featuredrange" as="featuredrange" template="abcpage/html/recommendedrange.phtml"></block>
           <!--marker for later-->     
       </block>
       ....
   </block>
```

I can successfully add my "target" block by replacing  "marker for later"
with the block call:

```
<block type="abc_articles/catalog_category_list_article" name="category.info.articles" as="category_articles" template="abc_articles/catalog/product/list/article.phtml"></block>
```

and it all shows up using $this->getChildHtml("category_articles") in the sidebarblock.phtml

However, I just want to add this on "catalog_category_view" .  I have a separate article-related layout xml file which is being picked up for other things but when I use this instead (clearing out the marker bit above):

```
    <catalog_category_view>
        <reference name="sidebarblock">
            <block type="abc_articles/catalog_category_list_article" name="category.info.articles" as="category_articles" template="abc_articles/catalog/product/list/article.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_catagory_view>
```

zip....nada...nothing...nowt and no block content.

Suggestions to fix please...guess I am just missing something fundamental here but cannot spot what (maybe because it is nearly 5pm).  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing that occured to me is a typo in closing tag:

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="sidebarblock">
        <block type="abc_articles/catalog_category_list_article" name="category.info.articles" as="category_articles" template="abc_articles/catalog/product/list/article.phtml"></block>
    </reference>
</catalog_catagory_view>
```

into:

```
<catalog_category_view>
    <reference name="sidebarblock">
        <block type="abc_articles/catalog_category_list_article" name="category.info.articles" as="category_articles" template="abc_articles/catalog/product/list/article.phtml"></block>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_view>
```

Let me know if that helps, if not then add a comment and we'll investigate further.

P.S. If that's the case then I advice to use any XML Linter in your editor which will catch and prompt you with any mistyping/misclosing tags.

Comment: Good spot on the typo but it doesn't fix the problem.  I did have linters for everything I use until recently - adding again to check through things.

Comment: I have it working now. Turns out the same "name" was used in the block elsewhere in the config file..